# <div> hides when I click a button

Tags: jquery, html

So, basically I created a `<div>` and with the help of JQuery it only shows when the button of "register" is clicked.

The JQuery command is a simple .show

The problem is that the `<div>` hides when I click a button inside it that is supposed to open yet another `<div>` for uploading a photo. The button is inside a `<form>` tag, maybe that? Or maybe the button being type='image' has something to do with it?

Any way to get the first `<div>` to stay when the second one shows? Or just to get the first `<div>` to stay after clicking a button inside it?

Here's some code.

HTML:

```
<div class='register-form-artist-js'>
<form>
    <span class='register-form-artist-image-button'> 
        Upload image: <br> <input type='image' class='register-form-image-artist-button' src='images/camera upload logo.png' />
    </span>
</form>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.register-form-artist-js').hide();
    $('.register-type-artist').click(function(){
        $('.register-form-artist-js').show();
    });
});
```

That's how I show the first `<div>`, I haven't created the upload photo `<div>` yet. I tried opening another `<div>` with the image button but had the same problem.

Comment: The code you've shown us won't hide the div when you click anything (just on document.ready), so there must be something else somewhere.  Look through your code for other `.hide()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.register-form-artist-js').hide();
    $('.register-form-artist-image-button').on("click",function(){
        $('.register-form-artist-js').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.register-form-artist-js').css("display","none");
    $('.register-type-artist').click(function(){
       $('.register-form-artist-js').css("display","block");
    });
});
```